# Wrong Number of Groups in Choropleth Using sf, ggplot, and cut_interval()

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, r-sf

I am trying to control the number of categories in a choropleth using `sf`, `ggplot2` and `cut_interval()` within `ggplot2`. Sometimes it works but with some datasets the number of categories is out by 1. Below is my code and the input dataset (7Kb) is here:
[ggplot-test-04.geojson](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1InCejWqbG4LptCbm0XlIuYkeC9rXFT5W/view?usp=sharing)

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

lga.sf <-  st_read("ggplot-test-04.geojson")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = lga.sf,
          aes(fill = cut_interval(value,5))) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu", 
                    name = "Legend" )
```

I am trying to get 5 groups but the result has 4:
[image: 4 groups]

In some datasets this code works fine. Sometimes I can work around the issue by choosing say n=6 in `cut_interval()` to get 5 groups. However, I find that frequently I cannot control the number of groups in the choropleth, which is critical for me. So far I cannot tell if my data has a problem, my code, or there is a software bug.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, `cut_interval()` is performing correctly, but there are zero observations in one of the cuts, so `ggplot()` ignores it.

(It happens to be the middle interval - you can actually see the gap in coverage between the second and third legend items.)

You can verify this by looking at `cut_interval()` with `table()`:

```
table(cut_interval(lga.sf$value, 5))

[1.44,1.61] (1.61,1.78] (1.78,1.95] (1.95,2.11] (2.11,2.28] 
          3           7           0           1           1
```